# passing this in a dynamically created row

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a row dynamically and below given is a part code. I wanted to pass 'this' in the js function. It gives me an error ***Expected identifier***

how can I pass this in below condition.

```
var tempRow='<td class="class1"><a href="#" id="'+ids+"LinkNews"+'" title="Viewers actions" onclick="javascript:showUserActivity('+userid+'ActivitiesNews','\'this'\');" ></a></td>'
```

Comment: `this` as an event argument should not be quoted, its not a string.

Comment: So how can I give ? with out quotes also it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the 'this':
it currently reads: `'\'this'\'`
but should read `'\'this\''`